# Bluetooth Write Function null error

Tags: android

I can not use this function on my code i have a null object error but it is not nul where is my mistake?

```
public void write(byte[] out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
    if (mConnectedThread == null) {

    }
    r = mConnectedThread;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    Log.d(TAG, "write: Write Called.");
    //perform the write
    r.write(out);


}
```

Comment: Please add a `return` inside the `if clause` to make sure your `r` doesn't become null

Comment: I am sure r doesnt null but not working i have a topic in here but anybody answer me maybe you can solve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51415000/bluetoothconnectionservice-return-empty-connectedthread

Comment: The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. i think this is my problem but i dont know how can i fix?